# Eclipse "this is not a CDT project" - how to figure out what is wrong

Tags: eclipse, embedded, eclipse-cdt

I am "quasi-generating" an eclipse project -
I have:
(a) numerous projects I need to create
(b) Every project has the same pattern of source dirs and include dirs
(c) And linker scripts etc...

So I have a small python script that reads a json file with specifics and outputs a .project and .cproject file

This works, but from time to time something goes wrong and I get the "This is not a CDT Project" message in eclipse.

Its very labour intensive to figure out the stupid mistake - my question is this:  Is there a way to get eclipse/CDT to tell me what it is choking on? For example a log file of some sort?

Please do not even suggest CMAKE - CMAKE does *NOT* work for embedded cross-compiling platforms with highly customized Eclipse packages from companies like Xilinx and Microsemi.  And the project needs to a CDT project, not a CDT-Makefile project for numerous other reasons. (Which for brevity I will not go into here)

Comment: What did your search for log files reveal? You might want to look in the installation folder. Eclipse writes log files, unfortunately I cannot check right now, here is no Eclipse installation. Would you mind to provide such generated project files? (The files are not that big, and you might want to add a minimal application, too.)

Comment: Anything in the _Error Log_ view?

Comment: Have you tried running eclipse from a terminal?  Even when it is in GUI mode it still dumps a load of stuff on stdout.

Comment: Thank you both - stupid move (1) forgot the ; on the end of &quot;, then spelled &quote;  when it is actually &quot; without the terminal e.